# Идентификация стилистического приема

Tags: тропы

Как называется стилистический прием, дважды использованный в предложении: "Носа касается тень запаха, а кожи -- тень тепла твоего лица"?

Answer (score 1):

Лексический стилистический приём метафора.

Comment: Вы думаете, это вопрос про тень? Я подумал, что здесь инверсия, дополнение вынесено в начало, подлежащее в конец. А вот насчет метафоры - несколько сомнительно, даже если вопрос про тень. Нет объекта с которым тень сравнивается.

Comment: Как я понимаю, это фантастика.Не "Прикосновение теней"? В фантастике и объекты фантастические. - речь о человеке и тени человека, а у неё не запах, а странное ощущение, отзвук, как бы воспоминание о запахе, не тепло лица, а воспоминание о тепле, почти тень.Тень запаха - запах сравнивается с предметом, дающим тень, он касается носа, как предмет.

Comment: Тень в данном случае - едва ощутимое присутствие, вопрос про сочетание "тени" и "запаха/тепла".